# Modal on IOS using tailwindcss in react glitches like this

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

[image: Glitching on IOS]

So I created a modal in my reactjs application, it's working with no issues on Android and PCs but on IOS it glitches and content isn't showing corectly (sometimes a little scrolling MIGHT and MIGHT NOT solve it). Here's the code :

```
    const backdropRef = useRef(null);
    function outsideClickCloseNav(e) {
        if (backdropRef.current === e.target) {
            setModalOpen(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (modalOpen) {
            document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
        } else {
            document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
        }
        return () => {
            document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
        };
    }, [modalOpen]);

    const defaultSizes = "w-[90%] lg:w-[60%]";

    if (modalOpen) {
        return (
            <article className={`fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen z-[99999999999999999999] bg-black/40 bg-opacity-20 backdrop-blur-lg drop-shadow-lg flex cursor-auto items-start justify-center overflow-y-scroll py-12 pb-40`} ref={backdropRef} onMouseDown={outsideClickCloseNav}>
                <div className={`${sizes ? sizes : defaultSizes} bg-white dark:bg-bg-dark-secondary rounded-3xl text-bg-dark dark:text-bg-light flex flex-col justify-between h-max`}>
                    <div className="w-full relative">
                        <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full px-8 py-6 pb-4 border-gray-200 border-b dark:border-opacity-10">
                            <h3 className="text-xl font-bold text-center w-full">{title}</h3>
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-times text-3xl sm:text-3xl cursor-pointer" onClick={() => setModalOpen(false)}></i>
                        </div>
                        {children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        );
    }
```

I tried to copy the exact code and put it in an another app, but still gives me the same thing.
I tried getting rid of conditional styling, but the issue persist.